# How to get Column values?

Tags: c#, sql

```
|No |Type |Num |
| 1 | a   |  1 |
| 1 | a   |  2 |
| 2 | b   |  1 |
| 2 | b   |  1 |
| 3 | b   |  2 |
| 3 | b   |  2 |
```

I have a Table with columns(`No` and `Type`) and I want to create columns(`Num`) with values. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: (1) Explain what the logic is.  It is not obvious.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Very unclear question, please take the time to explain your problem so that we can help you

Comment: It's not obvious what you want. In the first two rows it looks like you want to number the rows, but for the next four, you want something else. What are the Num column values?

Comment: That is weird magic. I mean how did you understand what the question is about? Title, Question body, and Answers all goes in different directions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split each type into two groups based on `no`, then you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by type order by no) <= 0.5 * count(*) over (partition by type)
             then 1 else 2
        end) as num
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `dense_rank`:

```
declare @tbl table ([No] int, [Type] varchar(1),[Num] int);
insert into @tbl values
( 1 , 'a'   ,  1 ),
( 1 , 'a'   ,  2 ),
( 2 , 'b'   ,  1 ),
( 2 , 'b'   ,  1 ),
( 3 , 'b'   ,  2 ),
( 3 , 'b'   ,  2 );

select [No], [Type],
       dense_rank() over (partition by [Type] order by [Num])
from @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

**create a method like below and call it**

```
    public ExecuteCommand(string columnName,List<string> values)
    {
        //here 'command' is instance variable of IDbCommand class, to execute command text in database

        string sql = "alter table TableName add ColumnName DatatypeOfColumn ";
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.ExecuteScalar();
        foreach(string value in values)
        {
            sql = "update table TableName set ColumnName="+ value + " where condition ";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
```